# How to upgrade casks with HomeBrew

Tags: sublimetext3, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I got this notice with SublimeText

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I tried to upgrade it using the command line:

```
 brew cask upgrade sublime-text
```

but I got this:

> ==> No Casks to upgrade

is that simply because HomeBrew is behind the release schedule or is there a better command to use?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're on Linux here and not MacOS because the Mac version of Sublime will download and install it's own updates and doesn't require a third party package manager. If that's the case, depending on the distribution that you use you may have more luck using the official repositories for Sublime, which are always up to date with the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

```sh
$ brew upgrade --cask [your cask]
```

For example:

```sh
$ brew upgrade --cask sublime-text
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula `sublime-text` from Homebrew Cask has not been updated yet. Check [`sublime-text.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/sublime-text.rb)

```rb
cask 'sublime-text' do
  version '3.207'
  sha256 'ed090251aa852a628ec664c5aa1bdd57e941852458f3ac0128d869e6e012cdcb'

  url "https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%20#{version.no_dots}.dmg"
  appcast "https://www.sublimetext.com/updates/#{version.major}/stable/appcast_osx.xml"
  ...
```

Homebrew is a community driven package manager on macOS. All packages/softwares are maintained by the contributors, not by the software authors themselves.